# Is there a more efficient (faster) way of searching and matching values in a JSON file in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an API that allows the search of information based on an order number like so:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/api/status.php?os='.$orderId)
```

`status.php` has the following code:

```
if (isset($_GET['os'])) { $orderId = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_GET['os'])); }

if (isset($orderId)) {

    try {

        $array = \JsonMachine\JsonMachine::fromFile($file);
        // using JSON Machine https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine

        $result = getOrderStatus($orderId, $array);

        if (empty($result)) {

            http_response_code(206);

        } else {

            echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo json_encode(array(
            'error' => array(
                'code' => $e->getCode(),
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            )
        ));

    }

}
```

The above loads the json file (currently 1.4MB, approx 3000 objects, 15 key/value pairs per object) and passes the whole decoded json to the `getOrderStatus` function:

```
function getOrderStatus($orderId, $array) {

    $resultArray = array();

    foreach ($array as $val) {

        $oid = explode(' ', $val['ORDER TITLE']);
        $oid = $oid[0];
        $oid = explode('_', $oid);
        $oid = $oid[0];

        if ($oid == $orderId) {

            $resultArray['status'] = $val['STAT ID'];

            $resultArray['email'] = $val['STAT CTRL'];

            $resultArray['mzId'] = $val['ORDER ID'];

            $resultArray['mcId'] = $val['COMPANY ID'];

            $resultArray['count'] = $val['NUM PCS'];

        }

    }

    return $resultArray;

}
```

if ($oid == $orderId) matches whether the id from the API matches the value of the key "ORDER TITLE", in which case the rest of the information in that object is relevant to the search.

Here is an example of two objects from the JSON file:

```
[
   {
      "INTERNAL ID": "914693",
      "ORDER TITLE": "0108491 A_PRODUCT_NAME",
      "COMPANY ID": "",
      "STAT ID": "1.2",
      "STAT CTRL": "example@example.com",
      "POST ID": "Post",
      "SML": "Transfer",
      "UPDATE": "17.06.2019 10:52:45",
      "TOTAL": "0",
      "NUM PCS": "1",
      "PAID": "",
      "TEXT": "",
      "PROBLEM": ""
   },
   {
      "INTERNAL ID": "914694",
      "ORDER TITLE": "0108494 A_PRODUCT_NAME",
      "COMPANY ID": "",
      "STAT ID": "1.2",
      "STAT CTRL": "example@example.com",
      "POST ID": "Post",
      "SML": "Transfer",
      "UPDATE": "17.06.2019 10:52:45",
      "TOTAL": "0",
      "NUM PCS": "1",
      "PAID": "",
      "TEXT": "",
      "PROBLEM": ""
   }
]
```

The problem is that I have no control over the format of the JSON file, since it is an export from external software.

Currently, I am searching and matching approx. 100 order numbers. This means that with the above code, for each order number - the API is called, the JSON file needs to be opened, each of 3000 objects tested for the match, array with info returned, all 100 times. This is why I think the process takes 40 seconds. While this is bearable, there could be as much as 10x more objects in the JSON file in the future.

What can do to make the search faster? I was thinking of calling the API with an array of order numbers, then opening the file once and matching each order number. Would this be the correct approach?

Comment: Store the information in a database and update it periodically. The json-file solution will not scale at all. And it is already slow.

Comment: `strpos` might be faster than 2 explodes per item.  https://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php  Regex might be faster too

Comment: @jeroen I have thought about doing this as well. I would just have to write a script to watch for changes in the file upload and then update the database. I guess it would allow me much more freedom to search by different columns etc.

Comment: @Fid More freedom and the speed is of a completely different order :-)

Comment: @jeroen Speed is of much higher importance right now. I'll see what I can plop together.

Comment: Does the API allow you to query for multiple orders at once via `https://www.example.com/api/status.php?os[]=1&os[]=2`?

Comment: You can make use of [`curl_multi_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to fetch multiple orders at once if the API doesn't naturally let you query for more than one.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, but this under my control, so I could make it expect an array of order IDs in the request.

Comment: Oh I see. You can also consider programming the API to accept filter criteria so that it doesn't spit out several MBs of unneeded data.

Comment: @jeroen fwiw, the API is under OP's control. It would seem silly to re-store data which is already being stored. It does beg the question as to why the app doesn't access the DB directly but this sounds like a micro-services environment.

Comment: The external app can export CSV or JSON. Unfortunately, the devs are very slow and unwilling to make any changes, so I have to deal with the processing under these circumstances.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That seems a bit unclear,*"The problem is that I have no control over the format of the JSON file, since it is an export from external software."* Regardless, if you need to search for information in a growing dataset and it already takes 40 seconds, storing it twice seems a practical solution :-)

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, after reading this again it is still a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing may be overly complicated, but serves the purpose well and should be resilient to the main `json` file getting larger in the future. For some background: The web app is used for an overview of orders and detailed information about the orders, which means touching a few local and external APIs. Approx. 5 people (5 browsers) may be using the app at any given time.

External software uploads a large `json` file with most of the information via ftp.

To automate the entire process, I found out about `incron`, which is similar to `cron`, but instead of acting on time, it acts on file/directory manipulation (creation, update, deletion, etc.). This of course requires ssh and root access to the local server.

```
sudo apt install incron

incrontab -e

/route/to/json/file/big.json IN_CLOSE_WRITE /usr/bin/php /route/to/php/load.php
```

`load.php` runs every time `big.json` is changed.

To shorten the load time, I created a database table with columns based on `big.json`. `load.php` reads `big.json` and saves each object as a row in the database table. The part of the code that provides this info via API now reads that info from the database instead of `big.json`, as suggested in the comments. This brought down the time to 22s, instead of 44s.

Although just converting `json` to `mysql` helped, I thought it was unnecessary for the individual browsers to keep repeating the load process, so instead `incron` does pretty much the same thing, but once and only upon file change.

`load.php` can filter unneeded data and also loads all external APIs and combines the data in correlation to the data from `big.json`, then saves everything to a new file called `data-full.json`. The size of this resulting file is about 16x smaller than `big.json`. The browser app with `datatables.js` then loads this file in a matter of milliseconds.

So in short:

- Load large `json` file only upon its update with `incron`
- Convert large `json` file to `mysql`
- Create a new json file combining filtered `mysql` data and external API data
- Ajax call the "static" new `json` file in `datatables.js`
- Add timestamp of when the new json file was last updated in `php` with `filemtime()`